# oracle in the real world

Tags: oracle

I've recently started using oracle after a few years of using mysql. I was immediately struck by how verbose oracle is compared to mysql. Four-word queries (like `SHOW INDEX IN < table>` ) become four-line queries in oracle.

My question is: how do *real* oracle DBAs interact with oracle efficiently. There must be some way to alias commonly used commands (like you do in the unix shell). I find it hard to believe that they would type something like

```
select index_name, column_name, column_position from user_ind_columns
where table_name='MYTABLENAME' order by index_name, column_position
```

every time they wanted to do something as simple as list the indexes of a table. Otherwise how can they get any work done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use an IDE like [SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/database/sql_developer/index.html) or [Toad](http://www.quest.com/toad/); these have a UI to browse tables, indexes and other objects without typing any commands.

Or in SQL Plus you can simply save commonly used queries as scripts in files, for example a script called show_index could contain:

```
select index_name, column_name, column_position from user_ind_columns
where table_name=upper('&TABLENAME.') order by index_name, column_position;
```

You would run this in SQL Plus like this:

```
SQL> @show_index 
Enter value for tablename: mytable
```

Comment: +1 - Also, if you have it licensed the Oracle supplied Enterprise Manager can show many of these things as well as aid in tasks such as segment reorganization, tuning, etc.  I find it somewhat clunky compared to tools such as Toad and SQL Developer, but it has it's uses.

Comment: To add to this, check out the Reports functionality in Oracle SQL Developer (View > Reports). I have recently started using this and have found it quite useful. There are a lot of time-saving snippets in there. For example, if you were searching a specific tables indexes:

Data Dictionary Reports > Table > Indexes > All Indexes

You can also add user defined reports.

Comment: _"Or in SQL Plus you can simply save commonly used queries as scripts in files"_ Recommended.